Nvidia drivers make my system completely freeze
On my G15 5530 I'm trying to set up dual monitors. When I connect my HDMI cable I don't see my external monitor. I've read articles here and on Stack Overflow that I need to install additional NVIDIA drivers.
When I tried install installing nvidia-driver-535 everything installs fine, I get through the Secure boot successfully, I enroll the MOK key with the password & then, after reboot, I can see the two monitors. The problem is, after less than a minute of working, the PC just freezes. Can't do anything and I have to force shutdown through the button.  I have timeshift to rollback. Is there a fix for this? Any help would be appreciated, I run Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Edit: here's a pic of the drivers I see under additional drivers

Tip: when logged in, hit Win key, begin to type Additional Drivers and click/select the grreenish icon. Wait for the GUI to fill in with a list of drivers, then pick one you find suitable and select it wait for install, reboot. Depending on your hardware and actual OS at least one should work IMO.

I tried 535 open, 535 proprietary, 545 proprietary and 545 open, all of them yield the same result. They work, but they brick my OS to the point of complete freezes

And you do not see 470?

No, I don't, only newer ones, I'll edit my question to include an img

I'd call that strange; I 'm on 24.04 and see 470-versions, similar to how you have 545.

I don’t have a solution, but I’m experiencing the same issue on Kubuntu 24.10, kernel version 6.11.0-9-generic, with an RTX3090 card, independent of driver version. I tried 550 (earliest I see), 555, and 560 (latest as of now). nvidia-sim freezes after the first double horizontal line and the whole system becomes progressively more and more glitchy until reboot. It’s the weirdest bug I’ve encountered so far.  It’s also weird that there’s zero online info about this. I hope someone manages to figure out what’s going on, because I have no idea.
